# Login form, customer registration form and add to cart is not working in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4-p2

I have installed fresh Magento 2.3.4 and Login form, create new customer form and add to cart is not working. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: are you on local host ? tried in Firefox ? use IP instead of localhost i.e 127.0.0.1

Comment: no, I installed it on the webserver, and in pub directory of another magento